# Setting price $8.99 or $8.95 instead of $9

Tags: marketing

Browsing publishers's sites I sometimes find prices like $8.99 or $8.95.

Why some publishers set prices $8.99 or $8.95 instead of $9?

Comment: It's not publishers; it's general retail. It's because people see the "8" and subliminally think it's a bit cheaper than if they saw the "9" first. Really. I don't have the studies to hand which showed this but you should be able to Google them.

Comment: This question is off-topic, because it is not about writing but about the psychology of price perception. It should be moved to cogsci.SE or closed.

Comment: @what This question might be on-topic at the [Economics SE](http://economics.stackexchange.com) (where something like your answer might be provided).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Just a long comment.*

It is important to note that x.99 is not the only price threshold. Others may lie around x.20 or elsewhere.

Price thresholds are not determined by the raw numbers alone, but also by the prices of comparable products, the type of product, the monetary system (the smallest coins in some currencies are .05 or even 1.00), and so on.

Also, it is not only important at what price points buyers drop off, but also the overall profit. E.g. (with made up numbers), you might earn more with 8.26 than with 7.99, because while you lose many buyers, the price difference will more than compensate those losses. Since there is another buyer drop off around 8.26 which would cause overall profit to drop below that of sales at 7.99, that is the relevant price threshold for your product, not 7.99.

The optimal price is a function that needs to be found empirically. Here is an example to show you the basic principle:

[image]

In this study, buyers were asked how they judged prices for a compact camera: "too cheap", "cheap", "expensive", "too expensive". The optimal price is where the curves for "too expensive" and "too cheap" intersect (here: 40 Euro). This is the price where you would expect the highest number of sales. You can also calculate the acceptable price range etc., but this would go too far here. I just wanted to give you an idea of the complexity of this question, and that (a) you cannot reduce price thresholds to .99/.95 and (b) price thresholds differ between products.

Answer (score 5):

This is a practice called [psychological pricing: .](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_pricing)

In a statistically-driven 20th century  marketers realized that customers tended to ignore, or at least underweight the odd cents in calculating the price of products. Once this realization took hold, the practice became widespread. It is a practice to sell more booka, or whatever.

There are different theories as to how the practice originated.  One theory is that by forcing cashiers to make change (and thereby record the sale) on the newly invented cash register, it acted as a theft control device. Another theory is that a newspaper seller  encouraged his advertisers to price their products at X.99, thereby giving back a penny of change for each purchase that could be used to buy the paper itself for one penny.

Comment: "I'm Earl Scheib, and I'll paint any car, any color for $19.95. No ups, no extras."